# Drawing hyperbol

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a hyperbola in html5 using the lineTo() method. I have the following code:

```
$(function () {

    var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

    context.moveTo(0,198);
    iteration = 0.21

    for(var x = 0 + iteration; x <= 500; x += iteration) {
            context.lineTo(x, 500/(x-250)+200);
    }

    context.stroke();
});
```

This works perfectly, but if I change the iteration to 0.2 or less, the graph doesn't appear on the screen.

See a demo on: http://jsfiddle.net/1kjpjryr/

Anyone any idea why the graphs fails at the particular value of 0.2?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are corrupting the path with infinity when x === 250.

In Javascript a number divided by zero is equal to Infinity. All good apart from the fact that the 2D context does not accept infinity as a valid coordinate and thus considered the entire path since `ctx.beginPath()` as invalid.

Because `iteration = 0.21` never lets `x === 250` it does not cause the problem, but with `iteration = 0.2` you will have `x === 250` same for `iteration = 0.5` or `1` or `0.1` or many others. Infact a suitably large value for the function in either positive or negative will corrupt the path, not just infinity.

You need to make sure that the coordinates given by the expression `f(x) = 500/(x-250)+200` does not exceed the max or min value that the 2D context can handle. (What the number is I don't know but anything outside your rendering range is acceptable.)

The following will fix your function

```
var lineStart = true; // semaphore to indicate start of a new line
var iteration = 0.2;
var graphMax = 10000; // |y| the positive max value that should be rendered.

for (var x = 0 + iteration; x <= 500; x += iteration) {

    if (Math.abs(500 / (x - 250)) > graphMax) {
        // skip the point
        lineStart = true;
    } else {
        if (lineStart) {  // is this the start of a line 
            lineStart = false;  // yes so move to and clear semaphore
            context.moveTo(x, 500 / (x - 250) + 200);
        } else {
            context.lineTo(x, 500 / (x - 250) + 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't `xStart` be mathematically derived from `graphMax` without wasting CPU cycles in the loop?

Comment: @ivanjermakov Yes